# How search and list files in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is of cource <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for file search, but it only for open files. What if it is need to find file by criteria, say which starts from "newFile" and delete them or move to another folder? The key problem that Intellij Idea Search implemented only for file content, not file names. Also with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> I can not list these files, select some of them and some action. It there something for batch file operation?

Comment: Related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99933.

Answer (score 24):

I'm using the following way to find a list of files matching a certain criterion:

- Open "Find in Path" menu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Enter nothing into the main search box
- In top-right corner, check the "File mask" option
- Use a tiny input field to enter your file mask, e.g. `newFile*` or `*.test.js`
- For convenience, you can also press "Open in Find Window" in bottom-right corner, so the IDE would show the search results in a docked toolbox

I agree JetBrains could make this functions more obvious / straightforward to discover and use.

Tested with WebStorm 2018.2.2 and Intellij IDEA 2018.3. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Vlad; 
Thanks for this detailed explanation. But it is NOT working.
In my project, under a folder I have multiple xlsx files. I tried to search by putting '*' in the path input field and mask field a value 'xlsx' and '*.xlsx' and choosing the scope as 'Project' or 'module' but in vain.
What is the mistake I was doing ? In Eclipse this is damn simple activity.

Comment: @PraNuta make sure you enter an asterisk first, before the file extension, e.g. `*.xlsx`

Comment: This finds the files, but is there any way to perform an actual operation on the files you returned?

Comment: @Kris Goncalves I'm not aware of such. Probably, using a file browser would be a better option in such a case.

Comment: Thanks - I did end up figuring out that using the shortcut ALT + Delete worked when selecting the search results in a docked toolbox. Presumably the other file operation shortcuts would work as well (ex. F6 for "move").

Answer (score 19):

You can use the "Search Everywhere" window.

To open the window press the search button in the top right hand corner of IntelliJ, or double-press <kbd>shift</kbd>.

[image: Screenshot of the Search Everywhere window in IntelliJ]

From here you can enter your search criteria, and it will return all matching files within the current project.

There is a checkbox to include non-project files if you wish. You can also use wildcards, and a forward slash at the start of the search will only find results beginning with the criteria.

**For example:**
Searching for `/newFile*.java` will find all `.java` files starting with `newFile`.

If you omit the forward slash, it will return all `.java` files with `newFile` anywhere in the file name.

More information on the Search Everywhere function can be found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/searching-everywhere.html).

With regards to completing batch file operations on the list of files found, I do not know of any way that you can do this within IntelliJ. The simplest method would be to manually selecting each file in the Project window whilst holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and then right-click and run your desired action on all items selected.

Comment: `Double Shift` allows you to select 1 file from the suggestion list at a time. He wants to select multi files matching a pattern and do some operations on that (cut, copy, delete), just like File Manager.

Comment: @Rocherlee You are correct, although I read the question slightly different to you. I read it as two parts; 1 - find files based on a criteria, 2 - run an operation on these files. I've tried to provide a suitable answer for both parts but I don't believe there's any way you can do both part 1 and 2 simultaneously.

Comment: By the way this question's title is worded, search engines will bring folks here, like myself, just wanting to search for a file by name. If that is what they are after this is the best answer IMO.

Answer (score 5):

**For Mac (OSX) users :**

Press `cmd` +`shift`+`o` (`cmd`+`shift`+`n` in older versions) and a file open dialog box will popup where you can even search the files normally or you can just use the camel-case shorthand.
Eg., `"HelloWorldIntro.java"` can be found by just typing `"HWI"` in the dialog box.

Comment: Windows users substitute cmd with ctrl

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows User   2021.3 checked below also work**

[image]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> 2 times

or

Press <kbd>cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> simultaneously 2 times